# Need a way to get all private IPs for Consul's retry_join without hardcoding it in the config file

Tags: terraform, consul, hcl

I'm trying to use terraform to set up consul servers on **Hetzner Cloud** with private network.

Since Hetzner doesn't support `auto-join` yet, is it possible to use go-sockaddr's `GetPrivateIPs` to get all private IPs available for `retry_join` in the config file? The go-sockaddr [document](https://docs.gomplate.ca/functions/sockaddr/#sockaddr-getpublicip) says `GetPrivateIPs` will return a space-separated string with all IPs. How can I make use of this function for the config?

From what I've read, the `retry_join` requires a literal array like this: `["10.0.0.6", "10.0.0.7"]`

Here is the setting in `etc/consul.d/server.hcl`:

```
  server = true
  bootstrap_expect = ${consul_instances}
  client_addr = "127.0.0.1"
  data_dir = "/opt/consul"
  bind_addr = "{{GetPrivateInterfaces | include \"network\" \"${ip_range}\" | attr \"address\"}}"
  retry_join = "{{GetPrivateIPs}}" // Is there a way to turn it into ["10.0.0.6", "10.0.0.7"]?
```

Here's the terraform data block that renders the server.hcl with variables:

```
data template_file "server_config" {
  template = file("${path.module}/server.hcl")
  vars = {
    consul_instances = 3
    ip_range = "10.0.0.0/8"
  }
}
```